# Using a loop to plot labels on a scatter plot based on their value

Tags: python, dataframe, for-loop, while-loop, scatter-plot

Hi I'm new to python and would like to plot the names of the footballers on my scatterplot as labels if their Goals or npxG are greater than the average values i have calculated.

I wondered whether I could use a for/while loop to go through the data and plot the relevant players names?

I've struggled to figure out the most efficient way for this to be done.

Please see the scatter plot and code below for additional context. Any help would be greatly appreciated, Thanks.

```
df = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/alexo/Documents/Data/football data/shooting_top5_leagues_21_22.csv',encoding = 'ISO-8859-1')
striker_df = df.loc[(df['Pos']=='FW') & (df['90s']>= 15)]

sns.set_style('darkgrid')
sns.set(rc = {'figure.figsize':(15,8)})

graph = sns.scatterplot(striker_df.Gls,striker_df.npxG_p90,hue=striker_df.League,size=striker_df.npxG_pSh,edgecolor = 'black')

# averageline x axis
graph.axvline(9.751677852348994,c='grey',ls='--') 

# average line yaxis
graph.axhline(0.34438111920973147,c='grey',ls='--')  

#adding label names for specific players 

#title
plt.title('Best Strikers across Europes Top 5 leagues 21/22',size=17,c='black')


# add credits
Notes = 'By Alex Orlandini'
CREDIT_1 = "data: statsbomb via fbref"

graph.text(
    36, 0.1, f"{Notes}\n{CREDIT_1}", size=10,
    color="#000000",
    ha="right");
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UJ6H3.png)

Comment: share the actual data, not a pic of it.

Comment: and which strikers do you want labels for?

Comment: Or if not share the data, at least share the link where got the data.

Comment: data would look something like this  
[name,Gls, npxG ,npxg_sht,
 Lewandoski, 35, 28.9, 0.18]                                                                                                      I want to add labels for strikers that have Gls >= 9.751677852348994 or where npxG_p90 >= 0.34438111920973147

Comment: Thanks. That's not really what I was asking for. We need the actual data, or a sample, to actually work with your code. In the future, in your posts, you want to provide as much code and data needed to easily reproduce/run your code on our end. Now since I love working with sports data, I really didn't mind pulling my own. take a read here on [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), specifically `Help others reproduce the problem`. I provided a solution below.

Comment: In terms of those labels, There's quite a bit of data points that meet that criteria. You'll have a very cluttered graph. Another option is you can look into `plotly`, and then you'd have a hover option that can display the label when hover above the point.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can loop through specific players and add the arrow and text.

Just a matter of getting the x, y coordinate of the data point, then deciding where to place the label. I had to pull my own data since you didn't share yours.

I would also avoid hard coding that average. I'd have that as a calculated variable.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns


#df = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/alexo/Documents/Data/football data/shooting_top5_leagues_21_22.csv',encoding = 'ISO-8859-1')

df = pd.read_html('https://fbref.com/en/comps/Big5/shooting/players/Big-5-European-Leagues-Stats', header=1)[0]
df = df[df['Rk'].ne('Rk')]   

df['npxG'] = df['npxG'].astype(float)
df['90s'] = df['90s'].astype(float)
df['npxG/Sh'] = df['npxG/Sh'].astype(float)
df['Gls'] = df['Gls'].astype(int)

df['npxG_p90'] = df['npxG'] / df['90s']
df['League'] = df['Comp'].str.split(' ',1, expand=True)[1]
df = df.rename(columns={'npxG/Sh':'npxG_pSh'})

striker_df = df.loc[(df['Pos']=='FW') & (df['90s']>= 15)]

sns.set_style('darkgrid')
sns.set(rc = {'figure.figsize':(15,8)})


x_axis_column = 'Gls'
y_axis_column = 'npxG_p90'

graph = sns.scatterplot(x = striker_df[x_axis_column],
                        y = striker_df[y_axis_column],
                        hue = striker_df.League,
                        size = striker_df.npxG_pSh,
                        edgecolor = 'black')


# averageline x axis
avgX = striker_df[x_axis_column].mean()
graph.axvline(avgX, c='grey', ls='--') 

# average line yaxis
avgY = striker_df[y_axis_column].mean()
graph.axhline(avgY, c='grey', ls='--')  

xOffset = (striker_df[x_axis_column].max() - striker_df[x_axis_column].min()) *.10
yOffset = (striker_df[y_axis_column].max() - striker_df[y_axis_column].min()) *.10

#adding label names for specific players
for player in ['Robert Lewandowski', 'Kylian Mbappé', 'Patrik Schick', 'Arnaut Groeneveld']:
    # Label coordinate, Custom arrow
    x = striker_df[striker_df['Player'] == player].iloc[0][x_axis_column]
    y = striker_df[striker_df['Player'] == player].iloc[0][y_axis_column]
    plt.annotate(player, xy=(x, y),xytext=(x + xOffset, y + yOffset) ,
                 horizontalalignment="center",
                 arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle='->', lw=2, color='black')
                 )
    

#title
plt.title('Best Strikers across Europes Top 5 leagues 21/22',size=17,c='black')


# add credits
Notes = 'By Alex Orlandini'
CREDIT_1 = "data: statsbomb via fbref"

graph.text(
    36, 0.1, f"{Notes}\n{CREDIT_1}", size=10,
    color="#000000",
    ha="right");
```

**Output:**

[image]

Or you can iterate through a dataframe:

```
#adding label names for specific players
striker_df['calc'] = striker_df[x_axis_column] + striker_df[y_axis_column]
striker_df = striker_df.sort_values('calc', ascending = False)
top_players = striker_df.head(8)

for idx, row in top_players.iterrows():
    # Label coordinate, Custom arrow
    player = row['Player'] 
    x = row[x_axis_column]
    y = row[y_axis_column]

    plt.annotate(player, xy=(x, y),xytext=(x + xOffset, y) ,
                 horizontalalignment="center",
                 arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle='->', lw=2, color='black')
                 )
```

To get something like this:

[image]